# DELETE FROM in MYSQL Stored Proceedure

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I've created a stored procedure using the following code;

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCandidate(IN `vid` integer, IN `aid` integer)
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `app_appointment` WHERE `vid` = vid and `aid` = aid;
    DELETE FROM `app_declare` WHERE `vid` = vid and `aid` = aid;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call the procedure `Call DeleteCandidate(1, 1547)`, rather than deleting where `vid = vid` and `aid = aid`, it deletes all the data from the tables.

Can anyone help me on why this would be happening. When I debug in dbForge Studio it shows the values of aid = 1547 and vid = 1.

Many thanks

Comment: have you considered CASCADE - or a simple JOIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different names for your variables. Otherwise the DB thinks you compare the column content to itself (instead of the column to the variable) and this is always true

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCandidate(IN `vidparam` integer, IN `aidparam` integer)
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `app_appointment` WHERE `vid` = vidparam and `aid` = aidparam;
    DELETE FROM `app_declare` WHERE `vid` = vidparam and `aid` = aidparam;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Variable has precedence over table column name, MySQL was testing variable `vid = vid`, not table column.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, both options are acceptable for the procedure in the actual dbForge Studio for MySQL version (in the letter body and in the answer). Call DeleteCandidate(1, 1547) is executed correctly provided that its variables match the table contents.